# convert "&euro" texto to respective symbol "€" in titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I recife a JSON with some values for example 399.00&euro but I need to convert the text &euro to € in this example. But when I receive something else like 399.00&USD I have to convert the text to $.

How can I convert the text after the number automatically?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replaceAll()` if you are reciving an String as response and them convert to JSONObject:

```
String responseAux= response.replaceAll("&euro","€");
```

Or do it when you get the String of the json object using replace():

```
   String value= jsonObject.getString(Constants.JSON_NAME).replace("&euro","€");
```

Comment: but i don't receive always this text "&euro","€". it can change and it is very difficult to make a replace for all possible situations

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
*@param {String} separator e.g: &
*@param {Array} symbols e.g: [{key:'euro', value:'€'}, {key:'USD', value:'$'}]
*@param {String} string to inspection
*@return {String}
/**
var convertCurrency=function(separator, symbols, value){
   if(_.isArray(symbols) && !_.isEmpty(symbols)){
      for(var i=0;i<symbols.length;i++){
          var symbol=symbols[i];
          var replace=separator.concat(symbol.key);
          value=value.replaceAll(replace, symbol.value);
      }
   }
   return value;
};
```